# Highslide: Pause HTML Slideshow when Gallery Expands

Tags: slideshow, highslide

I created a HTML Gallery that expands an image every window.
http://mmvirtualtours.com/0002/photos.php

When I run the gallery as a slideshow I would like it to pause when the contained image expands.
I am trying the following code:

```
hs.Expander.prototype.onAfterExpand = function() {  
if (this.contentType == 'html') {  
    this.slideshow.pause();
```

As it is it will pause after every transition in the slideshow. What do I need to change the contentType to and or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Remove this:

```
hs.Expander.prototype.onAfterExpand = function() {
    if (this.contentType == 'gallery') {
        this.slideshow.pause();
    }
};
```

Add this:

```
// Stop slideshow when viewing large image
function stopSlideshowAndExpand(element, config) {
    var exp = hs.getExpander(element);
    if (exp.slideshow) {
        exp.slideshow.pause();
    }
    return hs.expand(element, config);
}
```

Change the onclick for the large image in the highslide-maincontent div:

```
<a class='highslide' href='media/01.jpg' onclick="return stopSlideshowAndExpand(this, largeGalleryOptions1 )">
    <img src='media/s01.jpg' alt='' / border="0">
</a>
```